# Website displays PHP code using IP addess and not with the domain

Tags: php

I currently moved to a fresh Debian 7 install and I am running Virtualmin/Webmin. After I backed up from the old server and restored it on the new server, everything was working fine except using www. was causing the php code to be displayed. I kinda (but shouldn't have) shrugged it off and disabled www and redirected it to the .com

Now when some people visit my site using the IP address, it will also display the php code and not redirect to the domain. For most people including myself, using the IP will only display a blank page.

I would give the site name to show what I mean but it displays sensitive information in the php, obviously.

Any help with this would be appreciated. I am also running nginx on a different port, unrelated to virtualmin. But this issue arose before I had set that up.

I know this is caused by the webserver not loading the php5 module, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting my website options to use as the default domain for the IP makes it use the .com. I'm still unsure why the problem exists in the first place with the code showing, if anyone has a suggestion